# How to show all the children items in QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I tried to create a QTreeView as example from Qt

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html

[image]

When we click on the triangle before each "parent" item, the "children" items will be shown.

In my case I add this line to tree view

```
 myTreeView->setRootIsDecorated(false);
```

As the result, there is no more triangle before each "parent" item.

[image]

But the "children" items are also not shown any more.

My requirements are:

- disable the triangle before each "parent" item
- show ALL items in the tree, both "parent" and "children"

How can I do it?

Comment: Is [`QTreeView::expandAll`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#expandAll) what you're looking for?

Comment: @G.M.: thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Make shure to call that method every time you change the model data

Comment: @G.M. I think it would be useful to post your solution as an answer, so question can be closed and it get well documented for future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment you can programmatically ensure all items in the tree are visible by calling [`QTreeView::expandAll`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#expandAll)...

```
myTreeView->expandAll();
```

Note that it may need to be called again as/when child items are added to the model which, depending on the size of the model, could become a performance bottleneck.

As an alternative, it might be better to inherit from `QTreeView` and override the [`QTreeView::rowsInserted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#rowsInserted) member.

```
virtual void MyTreeView::rowsInserted (const QModelIndex &parent, int start, int end) override
  {

    /*
     * Let the base class do what it has to.
     */
    QTreeView::rowsInserted(parent, start, end);

    /*
     * Make sure the parent model index is expanded.  If it already
     * is expanded then the following should just be a noop.
     */
    expand(parent);
  }
```

This should give better performance for large models.